# How to detect a floating point audio file

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I'm working with pydub to check bit_depth and framerate from audio files (wav and flacc). How I can verify if its floating point?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth#Floating_point

I've tried to check the type of sample_rate from pydub, but its always int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample rate is on the X-axis of an audio file. It is always `int` and the value changes from 11025 to 22050 or 44100 Hz.

You are looking for the bit depth of the audio file. Older music had 8 bit. CDs have 16 bit. Floating point would be 32 bit. At first sight, it would be impossible to tell the difference between a 32 bit integer and a 32 bit float.

However, this information is given in the `fmt` part, at least of a [RIFF WAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file. The German Wikipedia has a list of file formats ([here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIFF_WAVE#Datenformate_(Format-Tag))). 0x0003 IEEE FLOAT should be what you are looking for.

In pydub, this gives you the format info:

```
from pydub.utils import mediainfo_json

info = mediainfo_json('example.wav')
audio_streams = [x for x in info['streams'] if x['codec_type'] == 'audio']
print(audio_streams[0].get('sample_fmt'))
```

With an example file that has 32 bit floats, I get `flt` as output. Your mileage may vary.